# Ping code in batch

Tags: batch

I got below script from a Youtube video but I want to know what is the purpose or function to put -1 10 in the ping command.
Can anyone help to feed me this info ! Thanks in advance.

```
@echo off

:top
set /p "ip=Input IP or target name to ping : "

ping -n 1 %ip% | find "TTL="
ping -n 2 -1 10 127.0.0.1 >nul 
goto top
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What is the purpose or function to put `-1 10` in the ping command?

An easy mistake to make but it is `-l` (lowercase L) **not** `-1` (digit one)

It is used to set the send buffer size (in this case 10):

```
`-l size`        Send buffer size (default=32).
```

Source: [Ping - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/ping.html)